# Opening a web browser from an Android application

Tags: android, browser, android-intent

I created an app to simply open a web browser and go to a specific website. However, after it's run for the first time, if I go to another app and run the app again, I will get nothing except the black screen. I knew I can find the page from web browser, however I wonder if there is a way to bring the content back when I launch the app and the user could get back to work from where he/she stopped.

here is my code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    /** setup the url and start a browser with 
     *  the hotmial.com and return to the user
     * */
    String url = "http://www.hotmail.com";
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(i);

}
```

Thanks guys

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the activity [lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/app/Activity.html).  You may want to move your intent to OnStart() for when the application comes back to the foreground after being stopped.

Comment: Thank you Bryan, but move my intent to onstart will cause the same webpage showing every time when I launch. Say, if I was in the middle of sending the email, I went to my music, and when I come back to start my app, then I will lose my email. So what I need is to go back to where I was before the interruption and not a new page.

Answer (score 2):

The activity may still exist when you run your app a second time; perhaps `onCreate` is not called.

After you throw the Intent to run the browser, shut down the activity so that `onCreate` happens every time.

If your application is here only to give a link to a website, this is much overhead in my opinion. Android users can make a shortcut to any website they want on the desktop, the shortcut icon being shown with the site's favicon in its corner.

Comment: Thank you. I would like to have a shortcut, however I will do something more later on so I have to create an app to open the web browser. And since I want go back and work from where I left, onCreate doesn't help me at all. I need to store the "session" information and come back. Thank you bro.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want to open the browser OUTSIDE your app. I know it seems like a simple(and trivial) edit, but I've never had issues setting it up this way.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    /** setup the url and start a browser with 
     *  the hotmial.com and return to the user
     * */
    String url = "http://www.hotmail.com";
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
    Intent i= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);  
    startActivity(i);

}
```

Comment: Thank you. However, it just works as my code and doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the android.webkit.WebView which will allow you to directly browse web pages in your app. Here the web content will remain persistent as long as the application is running. On the chance that your application stops you could save the url using WebView.getURL() which would allow you to continue from where you left of the next time you start your app. If this is what you want to do let me know and I will post some sample code.